# Problem with wheelcollider on bike game

Tags: unity

I have a problem with my first test on Unity, it's a simple motorcycle game. I found a script to start learning and runs very good, is this (answers.unity3d.com/questions/528298/bike-physics.html).
Well, the bike is moving good, and turns well, the problem comes when I try to knock down the bike. I'm using this example (docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html), and the movement is perfect, but the bike don't turns as expected, making a strange movement (a small jumps, seems a bug xD).
What is the correct (and easy) way to get work the wheels on bike, because on car works perfectly.
Sorry for my english, and I appreciate a answers for noobs to my question, please.

I'm thinking on the possibility of keep the wheelcolliders always straight and rotate the other parts of the bike...
Or here, the user reccomends a sphere collider...but, how to make a "wheelcollider" with a spherecollider??
I'm very lost...

A lot of thanks!!!

[image]

----- EDIT -----

PROBLEM SOLVED!!
This is the code I used to solve the problem, I don't know if is correct but works perfect for me:

```
//INCLINACION MOTO AL GIRAR
var tiltAroundZ = -(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * tiltAngle);
var target : Vector3;
target = Vector3 (0,0,tiltAroundZ);
var deltaRotation : Quaternion = Quaternion.Euler(target * Time.deltaTime);
// Dampen towards the target rotation
rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * deltaRotation);
if(Input.GetButton("Horizontal")==false)
{
if(rb.rotation.z > 0){
target.Set(0,0,-30);
deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler(target * Time.deltaTime);
rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * deltaRotation);
}
if(rb.rotation.z < 0){
target.Set(0,0,30);
deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler(target * Time.deltaTime);
rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * deltaRotation);
}
```

Comment: Can you describe that "strange movement" more accurately and what action exactly lead to it? Maybe it would help when you would create a video which shows the behavior. It would likely also be helpful when you would show us some screenshots of how you set up the object. For example what properties your wheel colliders have.

Comment: Well, I added a screenshoot and i uploaded to my youtube channel 2 videos with the problem https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvkbdfvLcQfYyCx5VXCvVGA

Comment: Oh, the strange movement is that when I press turn buttons (left or right), the bike don't turns if i put on script the rotation. If more velocity, less turn. When the bike is really fast, still in straight line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an object controlled by the Unity physics engine (one with a Rigidbody), you should never manipulate its `transform` or `position` directly. That confuses the physics engine and can lead to all kinds of weird results.

Always control the object through the methods of [Rigidbody](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) or [WheelCollider](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=WheelCollider). For any vehicles which uses wheels, you should do almost everything through WheelCollider. When you want it to turn, don't rotate the rigidbody, change the [steering](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelCollider-steerAngle.html) of the front wheel collider and let the engine handle the rest.

When you control a bike with realistic physics, it might get difficult to prevent it from falling to the side. In the real world the rider of a bike needs to keep the bike in balance, but your simulation doesn't have that yet. A simple solution might be to detect the current rotation and [add a torque](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) to rebalance it when it isn't straight. A more realistic but more complicated solution might be to do what a human driver would do and [adjust the center of mass](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-centerOfMass.html) of the rigidbody to prevent the vehicle from tipping over.

Riding a bike isn't easy in the real world, and when you want to simulate it in a game with real-world like physics, it won't be easy either.

But there is of course the most simple solution: When your goal is to create a game with very simplified physics, then you can also opt to not use Unity physics at all. Don't use a rigidbody *or* a wheel collider and move the object around by taking complete control over its transform and position.

Comment: @Jordi4321 I made some edits to my answer since your last visit.

Comment: With this answer...PROBLEM SOLVED!! Well, I need to make a lot of adjustments and add funcionalities, like different behavior deppending the velocity and add the yaw, but is a great start point. Here is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoLLrGzVE1w&feature=youtu.be I go to first post and I put the code I used. A LOT OF THANKS!!

Comment: Possibility to falling to the side is fun xDD. And probably i draw a rider, not at the moment

Comment: Well, after a lot of tries, your comment is perfectly correct...is VERY DIFFICULT to control the bike when I turn...and if more velocity, more unstable and always falls to the side. I tried to add a rider but I can't apply the forces correctly, always the bike falls down. The last you said seems good, but I don't know what is the start point :S